# What is the difference 'create-react-app <project>' and 'yarn create-react-app <project>'?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, npx

What is the difference 'create-react-app ' and 'yarn create-react-app name '?

I accidentally made a project without 'yarn' or 'npx'. And it worked.

I wonder why and differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create-react-app` might've been already present as a global package in your system so it worked without `npx` or `yarn`.

If you do `npx create-react-app name` then the react app is created after fetching the latest `create-react-app`. This is generally recommended.

See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/npm-vs-npx-whats-the-difference/